# Paypal WPS credentials

Tags: php, paypal

I have my application running nicely, I use Paypal WPS, I left the default values untouched, I tried with the sandbox and everything works nicely, but now, I want to release it, and I'm not quite sure about the credentials...
Default credentials are

```
<?php

define("DEFAULT_DEV_CENTRAL", "developer");
define("DEFAULT_ENV", "sandbox");
define("DEFAULT_EMAIL_ADDRESS", "sdk.seller@gmail.com");
define("DEFAULT_IDENTITY_TOKEN",     "6vwLEY_ogPGnoQac2a0x4PRsSGrmzJPMkyGbJtpiCSwrkYsNSYxWfPY2ZLO");
define("DEFAULT_EWP_CERT_PATH", "cert/my-pubcert.pem");
define("DEFAULT_EWP_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH", "cert/my-prvkey.pem");
define("DEFAULT_EWP_PRIVATE_KEY_PWD", "password");
define("DEFAULT_CERT_ID", "B62GVU8RWNBFC");
define("PAYPAL_CERT_PATH", "cert/paypal_cert_pem.txt");
define("BUTTON_IMAGE", "https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but23.gif");
define("PAYPAL_IPN_LOG", "paypal-ipn.log");

?>
```

How can I get real credentials? I don't find paypal help very useful... and I'm not used to using SSL, for what I could understand I need to get a private key, a public key, upload my public key to paypal and get a paypal certificate, but I don't know if that's right and, what to do with the other values.

Comment: I would suggest asking the maintainer of the application and/or read the documentation that comes with it.

Answer (score 1):

Having just done this myself, it depends on what you're doing with it.

If you're encrypting your buttons dynamically, you need the EWP variables.

[This PayPal help file](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_encryptedwebpayments#id08A3I0P017Q) explains how to get the various keys you need using your server command line.

I also found [a tutorial](http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php) and a certificate builder (linked in the tutorial, but I didn't use, so can't confirm how secure it is...)

---

The first step is to generate a private key and public certificate for yourself. You can use various online resources to do this for you rather than needing to figure out how to do this from command line on your server.

Once you've generated your key and certificate, you need to put them on your server with your website files and set `DEFAULT_EWP_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH` (private key) and `DEFAULT_EWP_CERT_PATH` (your public certificate) to the relevant file paths.

Upload the public certificate to PayPal (instructions in linked tutorials, but basically find the EWP settings and upload a new certificate), and set `DEFAULT_CERT_ID` to the Certificate ID it gives you for that file. It'll also give you a file you can download (their public certificate) - add that to your server and set `PAYPAL_CERT_PATH` to the path for that file.

`PAYPAL_IPN_LOG` isn't necessary unless you're using Instant Payment Notification, but is the location of the file you want to use for logging IPN records (if you want to use the default behaviour of the sample IPN listener (IPNListner.php).

`BUTTON_IMAGE` is obviously enough the image you want to use for your button.

`DEFAULT_DEV_CENTRAL` can stay as is. I think `DEFAULT_ENV` is a bit useless outside of development, as I don't know of an alternative to "sandbox" that works, since the standard URI is www.paypal.com/blah

Change `DEFAULT_EMAIL_ADDRESS` to your own PayPal account. You can also use your Merchant ID, but that seems a bit buggy on the Sandbox with EWP.

I've yet to find anything I'm using that uses `DEFAULT_IDENTITY_TOKEN`.